# Compress (reduce size) of audio and video files in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to reduce size of audio and video files in an Android app.
Can I use FFMPEG library for this, if yes please help with code or some tutorial link.

Or if there exists some other way to achieve this, please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are able to do it using FFMPEG.

Quick Google search:

[Here](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html).