# Best Way To Reduce Video and Audio file size in android?

Tags: android, performance, audio, video

We have audio and video recording option in our android application, the audio file format is .mp3 and video file format is .3gp just I want to reduce the file size from actual size without losing quality. For Example, the video file is 3MP it should be 2 or 1 mp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress (reduce size) of audio and video files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626997/compress-reduce-size-of-audio-and-video-files-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to reduce **resolution** (eg: picture size in width/height).

Check [**MediaRecorder**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) API manual for options :

- `setVideoSize(int width, int height)` command which can set video output size (note : *"Must be called after `setVideoSource()`*" from SDK manual).
- `setVideoEncodingBitRate(int bitRateNumber)` command can reduce filesize (in bytes) but could also affect visual quality. Some numbers make small file bytes but *visually* keep same image quality to the eyes. Research how bitrate settings affect visual image.

Experiment with above and see what works best for you.

Try first with `setVideoSize(width, height)`.