# Reduce the size of audio file android

Tags: android, audio

In my android app take the audio files in the phone and uploaded in server.
If the file size are too large i need to reduce the audio file size half of the original size.the below code i used ti take the audio file from phone memory.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 120);


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                uri = data.getData();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check : http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress (reduce size) of audio and video files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626997/compress-reduce-size-of-audio-and-video-files-in-android)

Comment: String commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/vk2/in.wav -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 64k -f mp3 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp3"; in this string where i want put i get audio file path